How to Bypass Press-and-Hold CAPTCHA When All Methods Fail?
I’m struggling with bypassing a press-and-hold CAPTCHA on a website. Despite trying several methods, including auto-key automation and proxy rotation, I’m still facing issues with detection. Here’s a summary of what I’ve attempted:
Auto-Key Automation: Used various automation tools to simulate the press-and-hold action, but it’s not working as expected.
Proxy Rotation: Implemented proxies to avoid detection, yet the CAPTCHA still detects and blocks automation attempts.
Other Techniques: Tried multiple methods including changing user agents, varying click intervals, and using different Selenium approaches.
Are there specific strategies or techniques for bypassing a press-and-hold CAPTCHA that might not be widely known?
How can I improve the success rate of bypassing such CAPTCHAs if traditional methods fail?
Is there a possibility that the CAPTCHA is using advanced detection mechanisms, and how can I address these?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
